# Is there a way to combine vlookup or index and match with the search function in Excel?

Tags: search, excel-formula, substring, vlookup

I'm trying to determine the reason a healthcare claim was denied, which is proving to be difficult.  I've looked at a few proposed solutions on this site, but nothing seems to fit my situation or work when I try it.  I want to combine the ability to search substring text with either vlook or index+match.

Here's the situation. There can be multiple denial reasons for a claim, and all the denial reasons are lumped together into one column in a report like this:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EhaaZkk6fr1QF_rAKiYIBUY4d8w4sCVR3C8JojNUuO8/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true

I've categorized the denial reasons into groups (see google spreadsheet link above) and want to create a formula to search for a specific substring and return a denial category. I was hoping something like this would work, but it doesn't: =search("(=vlookup(B20,A11:B11,2,false))",B20). B20 would be the insurance denial reason(s), A11 would be the denial code (199) and B11 would be denial category (enrollment).  Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: This is hard to understand. I suggest you draw a diagram with the fixed-width font showing what kind of data would be in your lookup table in `B1:C6` and what kind of row data you'd be using to index into it.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are approaching your goal will force you to write a very long formula that will demand a lot of maintenance when the requirements evolve (i.e. additional Denial categories, etc.). Instead I suggest to use Formula Arrays see this article [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-3BE0C791-3F89-4644-A062-8E6E9ECEE523)

This solution uses Formula Arrays and assumes the following:

- The Denials Categories table is located at `B6:C10`
- The Healthcare Claims table is located at `E6:I11`
  Enter this `FormulaArray` in `G7` and copy till last record then to columns `H:I` *(see figure 1)*
  *(Enter the* `FormulaArray` *pressing* `[Ctrl]` *+* `[Shift]` *+* `[Enter]` *simultaneously, you shall see `{` `}` around the formula if entered correctly)*

  ```
  =IF(SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH(
  IF($C$7:$C$10<>G$6,CHAR(135),
  INDEX($B$7:$B$10,N($C$7:$C$10=G$6))),$F7),0))=0,"",G$6)
  ```

[image]